# How do I assign a type to a union case from a Discriminated Union case?

Tags: f#

**How do I assign a type to a union case from a Discriminated Union case?**

**Code:**

```
type ValidationResult<'Result> =
    | Success of 'Result
    | Failure of 'Result

type ValidationError =
    | Error1 of Failure
    | Error2 of Failure
```

**Error:**

> The type 'Failure' is not defined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that. Discriminated union cases aren't types in their own right - think of them as constructors that return values of the DU type. So in your case both `Success` and `Failure` are ways to create a `ValidationResult<'a>`.

Therefore you'd need to do something like this, and it clearly doesn't make much sense:

```
type ValidationError<'a> =
    | Error1 of ValidationResult<'a>
    | Error2 of ValidationResult<'a>
```

This might be closer to what you're trying to do:

```
type ValidationError =
    | Error1
    | Error2

type ValidationResult<'Result> =
    | Success of 'Result
    | Failure of 'Result * ValidationError
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't: `Failure` is not a type. It is *compiled to* a .NET class, but you can't access this class from F#, it's just an implementation detail.

The normal workaround is to make an actual type corresponding to the case. In your case, it would be

```
type Failure<'Result> = 'Result

type ValidationResult<'Result> =
    | Success of 'Result
    | Failure of Failure<'Result>

type ValidationError =
    | Error1 of Failure<???>
    | Error2 of Failure<???>
```